Unimodality of multivariable quadratic functions
Are multivariable quadratic functions necessarily unimodal, so local optimum is always the global optimum? When the Hessian is indefinite then can we conclude the quadratic function is either unbounded or attains the extreme value at the boundary of its variables?

Edit:
(Sort of by definition. Local extremal points of real-valued differentiable functions on an open set $E \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are critical points. For twice-differentiable functions, the nature of definiteness of the  Hessian determines whether it is a maximum or minimum.)
Denote the function by $f$ and suppose $f$ has a local extremum in the (non-empty) interior of a set $E$. Since $f$ is twice-differentiable (polynomial), the assumption of indefiniteness of the Hessian leads to a contradiction.
Previous answer:
It is not clear if you are maximising or minimising. Also, extreme value can mean both maximum and minimum. In that case, I would suggest that you plot the graph of $x^2-y^2$ and check your second hypothesis.

Either maximizing or minimizing.  For $x^2 -y^2$ Hessian is indefinite, so critical point is not an extremum, and we see that function is either unbounded or extremums are attained at the boundaries (on the active constraint). Is this a general rule for quadratic functions?
